# What is a strategy in getting the best husband ( a dice game with changing face values)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

A task of choosing the best husband can be modeled by the following dice game.
Suppose you are allowed to throw a dice 5 times, and you want to get the biggest possible number with a given probability P of finishing with 1. You start with a normal dice, but in each new throw, a number on a previously shown face will be permanently replaced with 1. You can stop throwing the dice at any point, and accept a new-fallen number. What strategy will provide the best outcome?

Comment: The best strategy would be to stop playing around with dice and go on a few dates.

Comment: Please give an example. I do not quite get the "replaced with 1".

Comment: P=0 is also trivial: you trow until  you get >1 and stop

Comment: Example: I've thrown a dice and got "3", I want to try more, but two dots in that face are getting blackened and it become "1".

Comment: What does $P=0$ mean. That we want to ensure that we do not finish with a $1$ ? What if we throw a $1$ $5$ times ?

Comment: If we get "1" in 5 consecutive throws, we become "singles" for the rest of our lives, which is the worst possible scenario.

Comment: OK, let us become earnest. $1$ and $6$ in the first throw are trivial. Accepting a $2$ seems to be a poor choice, but no idea how to prove that we should continue in that case.

Comment: If we begin with a $5$ , continuing is only good if we throw a $6$ in one of the next $4$ throws. This has probability roughly $0.52$. If we start with a $4$, we should continue because the chance to get a better result, is roughly $0.8$.

Comment: How did you get those numbers? I did not practice solving these problems for many years.

Comment: $0.52 \approx 1-(5/6)^4$ (one minus the probability of not rolling a $6$ in any of the next four throws). $0.8 \approx 1-(4/6)^4$ (one minus the probability of not rolling a $5$ or $6$ in any of the next four throws).

Comment: It seems that OP wants a constrained optimization: $\max E[X]$ subject to $\Pr\{X = 1\} \leq p$. Not sure if there is a good method to solve this; but anyway since the number of step is small, you can always to a backward induction on it.